# Attendance Records Duplicating Across Multiple Groups for the Same Student

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm facing an issue with the attendance system in my Laravel application. I have a setup where students can attend multiple groups, and each group has its own teacher. However, when a teacher from one group marks attendance for a student, the records seem to duplicate across other groups where the student is also enrolled. I suspect the issue might be related to how the `createMissingAttendanceRecords`, `createAttendanceRecord` and `updateAttendance` functions handle the creation of attendance records.

Things I've checked so far:

```
The check for existing records seems correct.
The relationships between Group, Student, and Attendance models are defined properly.
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. If additional information or code snippets are needed, please let me know.

backend code

```
class ShowGroupAttendance extends Component
{
    use WireToast;

    public $groupId;
    public $groupDays, $monthDays, $monthDaysDate, $createAttendanceRecordsFlag = false, $selectedMonth, $isModalOpen = false;
    public $studentId, $date, $value, $studentName, $isReasonable;
    public bool $isUpdatingMonth = false;

    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->groupId = Group::find($id);
        $this->groupDays = json_decode($this->groupId->days_in_week, true);
        $this->generateMonthDays();

        $this->selectedMonth = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m');
        $currentMonth = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m');

        // Check if attendance records exist for the current month
        if (!$this->groupId->attendanceRecordsExistForMonth($currentMonth)) {
            // Set a flag to ensure that records are only created once during the initial render
            $this->createAttendanceRecordsFlag = true;

            // Create attendance records for each student
            $students = $this->groupId->students;

            foreach ($students as $student) {
                $this->createAttendanceRecord($student, $currentMonth);
            }
        } else {
            $this->createMissingAttendanceRecords($currentMonth);
        }
    }

    private function createMissingAttendanceRecords($currentMonth)
    {
        // Get the existing users for the group
        $existingUsers = $this->groupId->students->pluck('id')->toArray();

        // Get the users for whom attendance records have been created
        $usersWithAttendanceRecords = $this->groupId->attendance()
            ->where('group_id', $this->groupId->id) // Consider only records for the current group
            ->whereYear('date', Carbon::parse($currentMonth)->year)
            ->whereMonth('date', Carbon::parse($currentMonth)->month)
            ->pluck('student_id')
            ->toArray();

        // Find the new users that need attendance records
        $newUsers = array_diff($existingUsers, $usersWithAttendanceRecords);

        // Create attendance records for new users
        foreach ($newUsers as $userId) {
            $student = Student::find($userId);
            $this->createAttendanceRecord($student, $currentMonth);
        }

        toast()
            ->success('', 'Attendance is added with new students for ' . date('F'))
            ->duration(2500)
            ->push();
    }

    private function createAttendanceRecord($student, $currentMonth)
    {
        $groupDays = $this->groupDays;

        // Loop through each day of the week specified for the group
        foreach ($groupDays as $dayOfWeek) {
            $firstDayOfMonth = Carbon::createFromDate($currentMonth, 1);

            $difference = ($dayOfWeek - $firstDayOfMonth->dayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

            $date = $firstDayOfMonth->copy()->addDays($difference);

            // Check if the date is within the current month
            while ($date->month == Carbon::parse($currentMonth)->month) {
                $existingRecord = $this->groupId->attendance()
                    ->where('student_id', $student->id)
                    ->where('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
                    ->where('group_id', $this->groupId->id)
                    ->exists();

                if (!$existingRecord) {
                    $this->groupId->attendance()->create([
                        'student_id' => $student->id,
                        'group_id' => $this->groupId->id,
                        'date' => $date->copy(), // Copy the date to avoid modifying the original
                        'is_present' => false,
                        'is_default_status' => true,
                    ]);
                }

                // Move to the next occurrence of the same day of the week
                $date->addWeek();
            }
        }

        toast()
            ->success('', 'Attendance is created for ' . date('F'))
            ->duration(2500)
            ->push();
    }

    public function updateAttendance($studentId, $date, $value, $studentName, $isReasonable)
    {
        $attendanceDate = Carbon::parse($date);

        // Check if the attendance date is the same as today's date
        if (!$attendanceDate->isToday()) {
            toast()
                ->warning('Attendance can only be updated for today', $studentName)
                ->duration(1000)
                ->push();

            return;
        }

        // Check if the attendance date is the same as the current date
        $attendance = $this->groupId->attendance()
            ->where('student_id', $studentId)
            ->where('date', $date)
            ->first();

        if ($attendance) {
            switch ($value) {
                case 'true':
                    $attendance->update([
                        'is_present' => true,
                        'is_default_status' => false,
                        'is_reasonable' => null,
                    ]);

                    toast()
                        ->success('is marked as in the class', $studentName)
                        ->duration(1000)
                        ->push();
                    break;
                case 'false':
                    if ($isReasonable){
                        $attendance->update([
                            'is_present' => false,
                            'is_default_status' => false,
                            'is_reasonable' => true,
                        ]);
                    } else {
                        $attendance->update([
                            'is_present' => false,
                            'is_default_status' => false,
                            'is_reasonable' => false,
                        ]);
                    }

                    toast()
                        ->danger('is marked as not in the class', $studentName)
                        ->duration(1000)
                        ->push();
                    break;
                default:
                    abort(403);
            }
        }
    }


    private function generateMonthDays()
    {
        $now = Carbon::parse($this->selectedMonth);
        $this->monthDays = [];
        $this->monthDaysDate = [];

        // Calculate the first day of the month
        $firstDayOfMonth = Carbon::create($now->year, $now->month, 1);

        // Loop through each day of the month
        for ($day = 1; $day <= $firstDayOfMonth->daysInMonth; $day++) {
            $currentDate = Carbon::create($now->year, $now->month, $day);

            // Check if the day is in the specified days_in_week array
            if (in_array($currentDate->dayOfWeek, $this->groupDays)) {
                $this->monthDays[] = $currentDate->format('j M');
                $this->monthDaysDate[] = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d');
            }
        }
    }

    public function nextMonth()
    {
        $this->selectedMonth = Carbon::parse($this->selectedMonth)->addMonth()->format('Y-m');
        $this->generateMonthDays();
    }

    public function previousMonth()
    {
        $this->selectedMonth = Carbon::parse($this->selectedMonth)->subMonth()->format('Y-m');
        $this->generateMonthDays();
    }

    public function openModal($studentId, $date, $value, $studentName)
    {
        $this->studentId = $studentId;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->studentName = $studentName;
        $this->isModalOpen = true;
    }

    public function saveModal()
    {
        $this->updateAttendance($this->studentId, $this->date, $this->value, $this->studentName, $this->isReasonable);
        $this->closeModal();
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->isModalOpen = false;
        $this->studentId = '';
        $this->date = '';
        $this->value = '';
        $this->studentName = '';
        $this->isReasonable = '';
    }

    public function placeholder()
    {
        return view('livewire.placeholder.placeholder');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $students = $this->groupId->students;
        $showMonth = Carbon::parse($this->selectedMonth)->format('F Y');
        return view('livewire.teacher.attendance.show-group-attendance', [
            'students' => $students,
            'monthDays' => $this->monthDays,
            'showMonth' => $showMonth,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Group model:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'subject_id', 'teacher_id', 'group_fee', 'days_in_week', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'color', 'start_date', 'end_date',
    ];

    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
    }

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class, 'subject_id');
    }

    public function totalStudents()
    {
        return $this->students->count();
    }

    public function studentPayments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentPayment::class, 'group_id');
    }

    public function getStudentsBySubjects()
    {
        $subjectIds = $this->subjects()->pluck('id')->toArray();

        return Student::whereHas('subjects', function ($query) use ($subjectIds) {
            $query->whereIn('subject_id', $subjectIds);
        })->get();
    }

    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class);
    }

    public function attendanceRecordsExistForMonth($month)
    {
        return $this->attendance()
            ->whereYear('date', Carbon::parse($month)->year)
            ->whereMonth('date', Carbon::parse($month)->month)
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

Attendance model:

```
class Attendance extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'group_id', 'student_id', 'date', 'is_present', 'is_default_status', 'is_reasonable'
    ];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
    }
}
```

Student model:

```
class Student extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'phone_number', 'secondary_phone_number', 'course',
    ];

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class);
    }

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }

    public function fees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentFee::class);
    }

    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found what's wrong. The backend part is working fine, the issue was in the blade file, where i would get the very first student id (that's why there was error only with one student who are assigned to several groups), and showing it, so it would show the student from other group. all i needed to do was to add extra group_id check.

```
@foreach($monthDaysDate as $day)
                        <td class="px-6 py-4">
                            <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                @php
                                    $attendance = $student->attendance->where('group_id', $groupId->id)->where('date', $day)->first();//here i added group_id check
                                    $isPresent = $attendance ? $attendance->is_present : false;
                                    $isDefaultStatus = $attendance ? $attendance->is_default_status : true;
                                @endphp
***other code goes on
```